# Can't access object property value when it contains large strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below, you can see the output from these two logs.
One is of the object itself, the other is of one of it's properties.
Seems like a weird behaviour, where the property is set and visible in the first log, but undefiened when accessing it directly.

1. The string returned via Get request from a text file (blob).

**Important Note: The strings are a bit large (300kb)**

This is what the assignment of the string looks like:

```
await this.http.get(assetPath, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((content) => {
            /// Conent is the string representing the text in the file
            dynamicAsset.original = content;
            this.findAndChangeAsset(dynamicAsset);
}
```

2. Trying to console.log the object returns the object with the **property 'original' set properly**:

[image: Object itself]

3. Trying to access the property itself and log it, shows it's undefined

[image: Object propery]

The console logs whithin findAndChangeAsset. As you can see, they are one line after the other. **I can even change the order and it won't work. Crazy!**

[image]

Things I tried with no success:

1. JSON.stringify(obj) / JSON.parse(obj)
2. Accessing foundAsset['original']
3. Concat empty strings

Comment: What have you white-d out there? It might be blocking some of the display that we need to see.

Comment: Shouldn't `responseType` be `json` or `application/json` or something similar? Just guessing. It looks like json data that is returned, but because of `responseType: 'text'` the returned format is weird.

Comment: re: whiting a url, pretty insignificant.

Comment: re: application/json, I want to treat it a text. It might not be a valid json

Comment: what is `foundAsset`? same as `dynamicAsset`? or could it be a problem of accessing object before it was fetched?

Comment: same and actually called fron within the callback method

Comment: also, I can even change the order and it will behave the same. this is soooo weird

Comment: If you look at the one-line representation of the object, you'll see that at the moment in time when it was logged (_not_ the moment in time you clicked the arrow to expand it!) there was only `path` and `type` in the object and none of the other properties. So it seems like you attempt to access the `original` property before it even gets written.

Comment: Google chrome dev tools lazily evaluates object references, so even though you `console.log` spatially _before_ you try to access that property, in fact it might have been added _later_. To be absolutely sure `console.log(Object.keys(obj))`

Comment: will try to print the keys and report back. maybe it's an asynchronous issue

Comment: Where do you define/initialize `dynamicAsset`? If it's declared outside of the handler function and that function gets called multiple times (in case of of multiple `get()` calls), then each invocation may overwrite the previous value that `dynamicAsset` stores.

Comment: ok, indeed it was a synchronisation problem. I'll post a solution later today.

Comment: A good indication of the properties that loaded asynchronously is what @CherryDT and zerkms refer to above